# JavaFX 8 Overriding a property value for a specifc control

Tags: properties, javafx-8

I'm creating a JavaFX app. Is there a way for a control to override a parent container's property value with a different one which will be relevant only for itself?

My specific case is having an `HBox` which has a value for the `spacing` property, but I want 2 controls to be closer togather, meaning overriding the spacing property for one of the controls and only on a single side (like the padding property) so the controls will be closer togather? Or do I have to do it with an additional `HBox` which will hold these 2 controls?

If you could also answer the general case and not just the specific one, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for one property to be two different values for different children, as can be seen from the API:

```
public final void setSpacing(double value)
public final double getSpacing()
```

If the HBox were to save different spacing on a per-child basis, it would the child would have to be passed into the getSpacing/setSpacing methods.

Just use one outer HBox (big spacing), which contains an inner HBox (small spacing).